# Weighting dataset by one of its fields

Tags: statistics

I'm looking at the Olympics medal count rankings. I've created a points system for medals: a gold medal is worth $3$ points, a silver worth $2$ points, and bronze worth $1$ point.

How I can weigh the resulting points by population of the countries, favouring smaller populations?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it's useful to think in terms of the units that you want.

The number of medals is an absolute unit: it simply tallies the number of medals for each nation. Whereas if you want to control for population, then you *might* want to look at medals per capita, which is another way of saying medals/person.

However, you could also do more tricks in the same way. You might want to look at medals per GDP in dollars (directly): medals/\$GDP. Alternatively, maybe you feel that's not right, and what you really want is to normalize population numbers by GDP: $$\rm medals/person \cdot person/\$GDP = medals/\$GDP.$$

A useful trick is to note that units can be treated like variables: dividing by equivalent units "cancels them out" so to speak. So this is a way to approach your problem.

Formally, this is known as *dimensional analysis*, and if you're interested in the technique, you might want to look at the [Buckingham Pi Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty simple.  Why not just weigh inversely proportional to population size (i.e. divide the country's medal count points by its population)?

Comment: And if you don't like really tiny numbers, first multiply by, say, 100,000,000.

Comment: Yes Gerry it could be a scaled version of division by population size.